# Populate pandas dataframe in optimized way

Tags: pandas, optimization

I have a pandas dataframe (df_source) in the below format:

```
Unique_col  value1       value2      v1      v2
1           10001        1000        A       B
2                        10000       C       A
3           10001        10001       D       E
```

I have created another dataframe (d_dest) with following columns (A_dest,B_dest,C_dest,D_dest & E_dest).

This is how d_dest has to look like in the end:

```
Unique_col  A_dest  B_dest  C_dest  D_dest  E_dest
   1        10001   1000
   2        10000
   3                                  10001 10001
```

Currently, I do it using the below code:

```
  map = {"A":"A_dest","B":"B_dest","C":"C_dest","D":"D_dest","E":"E_dest"}

  df_source['v1'] = df_source['v1'].map(map)
  df_source['v2'] = df_source['v2'].map(map)

  def transfer_data(no, v1, l1, v2, l2):
     df_dest.loc[df_dest['Unique_col'] == no, v1] = l1
     df_dest.loc[df_dest['Unique_col'] == no, v2] = l2

  df_source.apply(lambda x: transfer_data(x['Unique_col'], x['v1'], x['value1'],
                                        x['v2'], x['value2'],
```

In df_source, for sample, I have just provided 4 columns but actually I have 50 different columns (v1...v50) and (value1...value50). Also, there are 500K rows.

The above solution takes ~10 hours to complete. Just wondering whether there is a way to optimize the code to run faster. Any leads would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the `(vN, valueN)` columns (`N=1,2`) respectively, and subsequently perform [`.combine_first()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to merge the columns while retaining non-NaN values.

### Code

```
df_v1 = df.pivot(index="Unique_col", columns="v1", values="value1")
df_v2 = df.pivot(index="Unique_col", columns="v2", values="value2")
df_ans = df_v1.combine_first(df_v2)

# rearrange columns
df_ans = df_ans[df_ans.columns.sort_values()]\
    .rename(columns={col: f"{col}_dest" for col in df_ans.columns})\
    .reset_index()
```

### Result

```
print(df_ans)
   Unique_col   A_dest  B_dest  C_dest   D_dest   E_dest
0           1  10001.0  1000.0     NaN      NaN      NaN
1           2  10000.0     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
2           3      NaN     NaN     NaN  10001.0  10001.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Bill Huang, does the pivoting need to happen after mapping?

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. Pre-selection of columns is redundant because index=, columns= and values= are all assigned. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of torturing `pandas` to get all that stuff moved, you could just bust this out into a dictionary and use some simple python scripting to manufacture a new dictionary and then convert that into your new dataframe.  I like Bill's answer, but I think you'd be stuck with a lot of pivoting commands.

Below seems to get the job done pretty quickly...

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

data = {'Unique_col': [1,2,3], 
        'value1': [1001,None,1001], 
        'value2': [1000,10000,1001], 
        'v1':list('ACD'), 
        'v2':list('BAE')}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_out = df.to_dict(orient='dict')
# print(df_out)

# figure out how many 'value' columnst to work with
col_source = sorted([name for name in df_out if 'value' in name])

flipped_data = defaultdict(dict)
flipped_data['Unique_col'] = df_out['Unique_col']

for r in range(len(df_out['Unique_col'])):  # iterate over all rows
    for c in col_source:  # iterate over the values
        label_col = ''.join(['v', c[5:]])
        new_col = df_out[label_col][r]
        new_label = ''.join([new_col, '_dest'])
        flipped_data[new_label][r] = df_out[c][r]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(flipped_data)

print(df2)
```

### Output:

```
   Unique_col   A_dest  B_dest  C_dest  D_dest  E_dest
0           1   1001.0  1000.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
1           2  10000.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2           3      NaN     NaN     NaN  1001.0  1001.0
```